# Trying to sync my wallet is actually making me depressed

Tags: synchronization

I really don't understand why it's so bad. I got geth light set up via terminal (because it was impossible to download blocks) by following the instructions in another thread and the blocks downloaded nice and quick. Yet the chaindata just kept going forever with an infinitely never ending bar with the overall umber always rising. What really upset me is when I tried restarting after a whole day of waiting it just started downloading the chaindata from the very beginning. Can someone advise if there is any option to have my wallet on my computer (not on a website) and fully functioning please?

Comment: I had the experience. Once the network finished syncing, the ETH was there.

Comment: Does anyone know how big the chain structure is? I saw some screenies of 11,000,000+ but this was from a month ago. Any idea what it is atm? And why does it start from scratch if I restart mist(although the blocks are there, just the chain structure that starts re-downloading)? Is this normal?